# Returning outer function from inner function on click

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, ecma

[image]

I want to return the value 'returnvalue' to the function 'returnFunc'
so that I can return that function to the outer function.

Comment: Please paste the code here, instead of the image with better explanation of the problem you are facing.

Comment: please respect your potential answerers by putting actual effort to ask

Comment: I second both previous comments. However, you're new here, so to cut you a bit of slack I'll clarify my main issues with the question (besides problems with the snippet). 1) If you're trying to return returnvalue to function returnFunc, then nothing needs to be done, because returnvalue is already inside function returnFunc. There's thus nothing to answer; 2) The question title contradicts the question description, so it's unanswerable.
Perhaps do a bit of editing to make it more clear? I don't want to see you driven away from the site - just spend a bit more time on clarity in the future :)